# how to convert rows to columns in postgres using pivot? let me count the ways

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

query:

```
select count(flag),flag 
from tablename 
group by flag;
```

I have the result set from table as following:

```
count | flag
---------------
2      B
45     ZG
3      RET
45     AAR
23     APA
```

i want result as

```
B | ZG | RET | AAR | APA
2 | 45 | 3   | 45  | 23
```

Comment: Did you have a look at  [the many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%28%5Bpivot%5D+OR+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29) that have been asked regarding problem?

Comment: i did not found solution for my question from them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'tablefunc' contrib module: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html